# C++ rename class member any ideas?

Tags: c++, class, rename, member

So here is my problem. Lets say we have a class that can do all the work but when I use it i want to have different name. Here is example of what I mean:

```
class A
{
public:
    int m_Value;

    A();
    ~A();
    void Func1();
    void Func2();
    // ... so on
};
```

Now create an object of that class and use it.

```
void main()
{
    A obj1;
    A obj2;

    obj1.m_NewName1 = 5; // obj1.m_Value has to be changed to obj1.m_NewName1
    obj2.m_NewName2 = 1; //
}
```

Could this be done?

I could do something like this:

```
class C : public A
{
public:
    int &newName1;
    C() : newName1 (A::m_Value)
    {
    }
    //Add some copy consructor and assignment operator
};
```

Now consider this for 100 classes to be renamed. Not very convenient

Comment: *Why?* I can't think of a single problem that it would be a reasonable solution to.

Comment: How would other code use it? You'd have to keep track of which object was using which name. It's best to encapsulate that and give it a uniform interface to avoid having to change when the implementation changes.

Comment: Public variables in a class (as opposed to a POD) is a often bad idea since it breaks encapsulation. Consider using private variables and getters/setters.

Comment: In class A are declared methods to read and write some data and class B that contains objects of this class with different name that means something.

Comment: I thought, he wanted a .Net property like behavior in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the variable names defined in class.!!!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in client code. If you want to represent different values by name, the way to do that is to use a std::map mapping names to values.

Answer (score 0):

will the following work for you?

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    int& ref_a;
    A(int i): a(i),ref_a(a)
    {`enter code here`
    }

    A(): ref_a(a)
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    A objA(100);
    printf("%d\n",objA.a);

   objA.ref_a = 10;
   printf("%d\n",objA.a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. Class A should not be changed and added references and members. Probably a MACRO could be used but honestly I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Could you please tell us the practical scenario where it is required? then we might be able to help.